# How to detect that POSIX locale is not provided on POSIX shellscript and POSIX utilities, portablily?

Tags: posix, locale

So far I have found that Termux is the only POSIX environment without POSIX locale; as a result the following command, for example:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<256;i++)printf"%c",i;}'
```

outputs not every non-null byte; the awk on Termux is actually GNU awk and it seems to depend on locale. The `-b` option, however, makes it succeed.

On [issue for ShellShoccar-jpn/kotoriotoko](https://github.com/ShellShoccar-jpn/kotoriotoko/issues/8) (Japanese) we are discussing how to handle Japanese and other UTF-8 strings proparely, but at this point the discussion is going somewhere out of compatibility; the latest idea doesn't think of what if GAWK is available but POSIX locale and UTF-8 locales are not available. Also what about non-GAWK awk? Maybe `awk '...' | xargs -I x printf x` is the most compatible idea.

First, how to detect that POSIX locale is not available? So far I have thought of these (never tested yet) (also I have found out that Termux does never serve `locale` command nor POSIX locale; only `en_US.UTF-8` is available):

```bsh
# 1
POSIX_LOCALE_AVAILABLE=no
type locale >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
   locale -a |
   grep -qE '^(C|POSIX)$' &&
   POSIX_LOCALE_AVAILABLE=yes
}

# 2
export LC_ALL=C
POSIX_LOCALE_AVAILABLE=no
case "$LC_ALL" in ('C')
   POSIX_LOCALE_AVAILABLE=yes
;;esac

# 3
POSIX_LOCALE_AVAILABLE=no
case "$(
   LC_ALL=C awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<256;i++)printf"%c",i;}' |
   od -A n -t x1 -v |
   tr ABCDEF abcdef |
   tr -Cd abcdef1234567890
)" in ("$(
   awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<256;i++)printf"%02x",i;}'
)")
   POSIX_LOCALE_AVAILABLE=yes
;;esac
```

But do they work on every POSIX environment? If not, any alternatives?

Comment: #2 just confirms that you’ve set `LC_ALL=C`, the shell doesn’t restrict the values that can be specified.

Comment: Thanks; that did never solve anything, as you said so. I confirmed it on my Termux.

Comment: The best that you can do is prove that it is available. You can't prove a negative: You can't prove that all swans are white.  I have seen many white swans, and no non-white swans,  but this proves nothing. Eventually the hypothesis (not proof) that all swans are white was disproved, when black swans were found.

Comment: So does that mean that we have to believe that #1 and #3 are the ways to detect that POSIX locale IS available? Also we would have to list all POSIX-compliant and POSIX-like environments and validate for all of them to confirm my hypithesis works everywhere.

Comment: #2 is a dummy (as already noted) and both other examples do not work on a typical POSIX platform because they do not create the needed constraints to call the POSIX versions of the commands. BTW: The existence of the C locale is required on a POSIX compliant platform, so why do you like to test at all?

Comment: @schily Those are just pseudo tests; all of them relies on utilities' features. Also should have I noted that #3 actually relies on GAWK; it depends on locale by default. The 2nd paragraph (On issues for...) of OP post says why I made this post. If it's completely impossible to detect existence of the C locale, we need to make software work without POSIX locale, too.

Comment: If you like to make your script POSIX compliant, you need to set PATH to the result from `getconf PATH`. I cannot see a dependence to GAWK since you do not use the GNU option `-b` in the scripts. It would help, if you did explain your exact problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this (requires other locales too: UTF-8, in this case):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
export LC_ALL=C
# alternatively:
# a="$(printf \\343\\201\\202)" # actually あ
# case "$(mkdir "$a" && ls -dq "$a" && rmdir "$a")" in ("$a")
# end alternative
case "$(mkdir あ && ls -dq あ && rmdir あ)" in (あ)
  echo NO
;;(*'?'*)
  echo YES
;;(*)
  echo WTF
;;esac
```

The script above outputs whether C locale is available or not.

`ls -q` should replace non-ASCII characters with `?`: this should fail if `export`ing does not actually change the locale.

The uncommented version above may fail if you're a [yash](https://yash.osdn.jp/index.html.en) user and `LANG` is not UTF-8: try commented one, please (I have no ideas if it works).

(PS. Worked on version 2.51 of yash; `. the_script_above.sh` to fail)

Answer (score 0):

How about this, as @schily commented:

```bsh
if command -p getconf PATH | grep .; then
   : 'LC_ALL=C is available'
else
   : 'LC_ALL=C is not available'
fi
```

I tried on Termux and Arch GNU/Linux; seemed working.